# Error installing packages and apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was trying to install mariadb-server but while doing it it gives me errors, trying to do apt-get update gives me more or less the same errors.

**This is the command output for apt-get update**:

```
root@autoapi:~# sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  System error resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  System error resolving 'it.archive.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  System error resolving 'it.archive.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  System error resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  System error resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  System error resolving 'it.archive.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  System error resolving 'it.archive.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  System error resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  System error resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  System error resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Server Information**:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

**How do I fix it?**

Comment: This may be a problem with the server you use. Wait a bit, or select another server.

Comment: How do I do it as a terminal?
And once done, how can I put the current one back?

Comment: Unless this is an headless server you don't need commands to do it, it's much faster by using "Software & Updates". And at least the PPA for Oracle Java should be removed because it no longer works.

Comment: I'm in a server with ssh so the only way to manage the machine is by using the terminal.

Comment: If you are a server administrator, you probably should be able to find out how sources are edited from the terminal. This configuration lives under /etc/apt.

Comment: Today I continue to encounter this problem, I tried to use the solutions you reported but I can't solve. **PS**: I remind you that I can only use the terminal via ssh because they are on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Check your iptables rules. You probably forgot to specify permissions for the **lo** interface and rules for incoming connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo apt-get update
```

That will remove the existing apt-get cache and force the redownload of everything. If that doesnt fix it, you will need to manually crawl through your software sources list and remove the dead entries.

Here's a great article on how to fix most apt-get errors as well:
[Fix apt-get errors](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-update-errors/)

Comment: Today I continue to encounter this problem, I tried to use the solutions you reported but I can't solve.

**PS**: I remind you that I can only use the terminal via ssh because they are on a server.

Comment: Alright. Can you try this command: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list     That will allow you to view your sources in the terminal and then delete the onese you no longer need or that dont work. When finished, just press control-X and then save the file under the same name. Then sudo apt-get update and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/dns-related-issues-with-custom-carrier-board-and-l4t-35-3-1/255657 and changed most of the permissions on /etc, /etc/systemd, / etc/systemd/system, /usr, /usr/lib, /usr/lib/systemd, /usr/lib/systemd/system to 755 permissions for the most part. The reason for my error is that I set 777 permissions on all directories and files under /root, and update is more sensitive to permissions, and its security mechanism is more demanding, so sudo apt-get update will always report the error.